# Is it possible to push commit after specific tag and not replace current origin HEAD

Tags: git

I've got some changes that should goes to old version of my code. Master branch has tags from 1.x to 2.x with braking changes in 2.x. Is it possible to push some commit after specific tag and not affect code with tag after 2.0?

that's what i'm already done:

`git checkout tagNumber`

`git cherry-pick newBranch`

If it possible what exactly should i do next? Just push to origin master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you checked out a tag, you have a detached HEAD, so your cherry-picked commit is not on any branch or other ref. So after the cherry-pick, you have to move the tag to the newly created commit. Then just push that tag to the remote. The tag will not be an ancestor of later commits anymore, as you effectively branched out and tagged on that branch. But no other commit will be affected in the remote, as you just push a new commit where the tag now is pointing to.